# How to execute program in linked docker containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

#### Setup

Currently I have two docker containers. First container is **webapp** host -this is where user uploads files. Second container is **pipeline** host -used to process uploaded files.

#### Solution

Currently I am using **ssh** within **webapp** container to execute *BAP* program installed on **pipeline** container.

`root@webapp-dev:/# ssh pipeline BAP /tmp/file.txt`

#### Question

Is there any native docker solution that would allow me to execute programs between linked containers without using **ssh** ?

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of docker is to separate services from each other.
Have you thought about [shared volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/volume-shared-filesystems) and having a script run inside the *pipeline* container which checks for new files?

If you really need to execute some command in another container you could give your webapp container access to the docker socket and install the docker client. Then you could execute `docker exec pipeline ...`. But you probably want to use docker-in-docker so that your *webapp* container only has access to itself and the *pipeline* container.

Comment: I am using **volumes** for data sharing between containers. However, I was thinking that there is some docker-ish solution for my use case. I will stick with **ssh** since it is simple solution. If it is about docker-in-docker (like Russian nested dolls) then I think it is just doing something wrong.

Comment: docker-in-docker has it's use cases, for example having a build server spawning build-containers without given the build-server (container) access to the docker-socket of the host.